# Python: data Structures inside another

Tags: python, perl, memory, structure

In Perl you can do stuff like this:

```
my $data->[texts}->{text1} = "hey";
print data->{texts}->{text1};
```

and it will print "hey". It is like a data structure (sort of array) inside another data structure...

Obviously this is possible in Python:

```
data = { 'jack': 4098, 'sape': 4139 }
print data['jack'];
```

But I want something like: data['texts']['text1'] like it was done in Perl.

And I need to be able to easily remove and add to this structure...

Help?

Comment: Then nest elements `data = { "names":{'jack': 4098, 'sape': 4139 }}`, `data["names"]["jack"] ->4098`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using [`dict` object](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm) here. It can store any type of elements you want, including another `dict` object.

That means, you can initialize your `data` like:

```
data = {'jack': {'age': 20, 
                 'gender': 'M'
                }, 

        'sape': {'age': 35, 
                 'gender': 'F'
                } 
       }
```

And then refer to it's internal values:

```
print(data['jack']['age'] # prints "20"
```

Comment: Worked. Thanks man!

Answer (score -2):

The bellow code describes your required data structure

code:

```
rec = {'name': {'first': 'Bob', 'last': 'Smith'},
                  'job': ['dev', 'mgr'],
                  'age': 40.5}

rec['name'] # 'Name' is a nested dictionary
{'last': 'Smith', 'first': 'Bob'}

rec['name']['last'] # Index the nested dictionary
'Smith'

 rec['job'] # 'Job' is a nested list
['dev', 'mgr']

 rec['job'][-1] # Index the nested list
'mgr'

 rec['job'].append('janitor') # Expand Bob's job description in-place

 rec
{'age': 40.5, 'job': ['dev', 'mgr', 'janitor'], 'name': {'last': 'Smith', 'first':
'Bob'}}
```

Reference
https://bdhacker.wordpress.com/2010/02/27/python-tutorial-dictionaries-key-value-pair-maps-basics/